# Is it possible to remove transparent pixels from bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

In my application i am taking screenshot if the image doesn't fill imageView then transparent pixels are added to bitmap.Is it possible to remove transparent pixels from bitmap or take screenshot without transparent pixels.Thanks in advance.

Comment: View content = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
   content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

Comment: i am capturing screen by using this code

Comment: bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);  and saving using this format

Answer (score 20):

This method is a lot faster:

```
static Bitmap trim(Bitmap source) {
    int firstX = 0, firstY = 0;
    int lastX = source.getWidth();
    int lastY = source.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[source.getWidth() * source.getHeight()];
    source.getPixels(pixels, 0, source.getWidth(), 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    loop:
    for (int x = 0; x < source.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < source.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                firstX = x;
                break loop;
            }
        }
    }
    loop:
    for (int y = 0; y < source.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = firstX; x < source.getWidth(); x++) {
            if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                firstY = y;
                break loop;
            }
        }
    }
    loop:
    for (int x = source.getWidth() - 1; x >= firstX; x--) {
        for (int y = source.getHeight() - 1; y >= firstY; y--) {
            if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                lastX = x;
                break loop;
            }
        }
    }
    loop:
    for (int y = source.getHeight() - 1; y >= firstY; y--) {
        for (int x = source.getWidth() - 1; x >= firstX; x--) {
            if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                lastY = y;
                break loop;
            }
        }
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, firstX, firstY, lastX - firstX, lastY - firstY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, your answer saved me. But I can't understand, why it's a lot of faster?

Comment: I guess I should have said it usually is a lot faster.  First it scans left to right to find the left most non-transparent pixel. Then it scans top to bottom but only looking at values equal or higher to this X coordinate.  Then does the same from the bottom and right pixels. This way it doesn't have to scan all pixels.

Comment: Also, copying the bitmap to an array and processing that array is MUCH faster than using Bitmap.getPixel()

Comment: it's trimming some text written at the bottom of image

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It's amazing

Answer (score 12):

I have done this way and it works great.

```
public static Bitmap createTrimmedBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    int imgHeight = bmp.getHeight();
    int imgWidth  = bmp.getWidth();
    int smallX=0,largeX=imgWidth,smallY=0,largeY=imgHeight;
    int left=imgWidth,right=imgWidth,top=imgHeight,bottom=imgHeight;
    for(int i=0;i<imgWidth;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<imgHeight;j++)
        {
            if(bmp.getPixel(i, j) != Color.TRANSPARENT){
                if((i-smallX)<left){
                    left=(i-smallX);
                }
                if((largeX-i)<right)
                {
                    right=(largeX-i);
                }
                if((j-smallY)<top)
                {
                    top=(j-smallY);
                }
                if((largeY-j)<bottom)
                {
                    bottom=(largeY-j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "left:" + left + " right:" + right + " top:" + top + " bottom:" + bottom);
    bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,left,top,imgWidth-left-right, imgHeight-top-bottom);

    return bmp;

}
```

Comment: perfect! Only think to make sure before using this is Config of your Bitmap whether it is 'Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888' if so this works like a charm !!

Comment: Thanks Bro Your answer is perfect.
But i want to add some space all 4 side like padding so what to do changes in this code?

Answer (score 0):

```java
Bitmap imageWithBG = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),image.getConfig());  // Create another image the same size
imageWithBG.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);  // set its background to white, or whatever color you want
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageWithBG);  // create a canvas to draw on the new image
canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0f, 0f, null); // draw old image on the background
image.recycle();  // clear out old image
```

Answer (score -1):

To trim crop transparent borders of a image in Android you ca use 
this arrange. Work faster because don't need read all pixels, it just slice the bitmap, more details: [CropTrimTransparentImage](https://github.com/AlvaroMenezes/CropTrimTransparentImage)

```
public Bitmap crop (Bitmap bitmap){

    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();

    int[] empty = new int[width];
    int[] buffer = new int[width];
    Arrays.fill(empty,0);

    int top = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int botton = height;
    int right = width;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        bitmap.getPixels(buffer, 0, width, 0, y, width, 1);
        if (!Arrays.equals(empty, buffer)) {
            top = y;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int y = height - 1; y > top; y--) {
        bitmap.getPixels(buffer, 0, width, 0, y, width, 1);
        if (!Arrays.equals(empty, buffer)) {
            botton = y;
            break;
        }
    }


    int bufferSize = botton -top +1;
    empty = new int[bufferSize];
    buffer = new int[bufferSize];
    Arrays.fill(empty,0);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        bitmap.getPixels(buffer, 0, 1, x, top + 1, 1, bufferSize);
        if (!Arrays.equals(empty, buffer)) {
            left = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int x = width - 1; x > left; x--) {
        bitmap.getPixels(buffer, 0, 1, x, top + 1, 1, bufferSize);
        if (!Arrays.equals(empty, buffer)) {
            right = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    Bitmap cropedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, left, top, right-left, botton-top);
    return cropedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: It crashes with "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()"