# set imageview in android-studio

Tags: android

Im trying to add 3 imageview with text, but i have problems with the image.

there coming some emty space under and over the image, so the image is been like a square.
And i have problem to change the other image and text.
It is like a layer around the image.

Like this:

[image]

This is my code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView4"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/tuna" />
```

Comment: try adding this `android:scaleType="center"` in your imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set adjustViewBounds to true and mess around with the scale types.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your image file. It consists of transparent pixels.

you can either remove those using photoshop if you are adding images manually. or if you are getting that image from the server you try below answer to remove it via code. [remove transparent pixels from bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41785424/5235032)

Answer (score 0):

try to adjust the width and height of the image file using photo editor (ex. Adobe photoshop)